# Load data into Mariadb with files containing (((

Tags: mariadb, heidisql, mariasql, mariadb-10.5

I'm completely new to import CSV into MariaDB
I have a CSV with the following columns that I am trying to import into a new DB.
WKT,id,title_no,status,type,land_district,issue_date,guarantee_status,estate_description,owners,spatial_extents_shared
And each line is in the format

"(((174.7 -36.5,174.7 -36.7,174.7 -36.7,174.7 -36.7,174.7 -36.7)))",310,N521,LIVE,Freehold,North,1999/03/20 00:00:00,Guarantee,"Parked,Deposited,8 m2",John Doe,F

So
WKT = "(((174.7 -36.5,174.7 -36.7,174.7 -36.7,174.7 -36.7,174.7 -36.7)))"

id = 310
etc

I've been trying to use the LOAD DATA INFILE with all the different options but the problem is the WKT column that has multiple commas, with double quotes but another column has quotes. The WKT column parentheses and I feel I need to somehow use that as the column separator but I'm lost how to do it.

Please can anyone help on how to import the above line?
I've spent way to0 long and long nights trying to work it out.

Many thanks
Mike

Comment: please show at least one thing you've tried with load data infile options and what happened and how you want it different?  also please edit your question to show (as text, not an image) output of `show create table yourtable name;`; it helps people answer more quickly

Comment: Your data is not in CSV format. CSV format denotes that the deilimiter of fields is not part of the data, which isn't the case.